# ReactJs, NextJs SSR динамического контента в NextJs 13

Tags: reactjs, node.js, nextjs, ssr

Раньше для пререндера страницы для каждого запроса использовался `getServerSideProps`. Но с новой маршрутизацией он не работает.

Теперь пререндер выглядит следующим образом:

```
export default async function Home() {

  const response = await fetch(url)
```

Но как я понял, это способ статического пререндера. При попытке собрать билд с этим кодом он падает, так как не может выполнить запрос (на момент билда url недоступен).

В документации NextJs написано, что чтобы не указание явно не кешировать запрос должно привести к динамической загрузки данных:

```
fetch('https://...', { cache: 'no-store' })
```

Но этого не происходит

**Как в 13 версии NextJs с новым роутингом сделать динамически SSR запрос?**

Comment: Прикрепите ошибку и код своего компонента. Данные фетчатся, когда клиент запрашивает компонент.

Comment: @xydope нет, nextjs пытается сделать пререндер статической страницы, соответствующую ошибку и выдает. Мне нужно явно указать что страиница динамическая и ее нужно рендерить на каждый запрос (Dynamically Rendered, Not Cached)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Чтобы явно указать что страница динамичиская необходимо из нее экспортировать константу

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export default function MyComponent() {}
...
```

Подробности можно найти в разделе [Route Segment Config](https://%20https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) документации